# embedded Jetty start without certificate and when cert available load it

Tags: java-8, jetty, embedded-jetty

I have embedded Jetty server in my Java code. I am loading a `SSL` certificate by using `SslContextFactory` class. My problem is when Jetty server starts that time `.jks` file is not present at the mentioned file path because it is generated dynamically and stores in the path. As `.jks` file is not present so server is not starting and giving `NullPointerException`. I will use `sslContextFactory.reload()` when certificate available on path but I am not sure how to deal with `NullPointerException` at the starting time.
Is there way to tell Jetty start without certificate and when `sslContextFactory.reload()` reloads the certificate.

**Update**

Jetty Version : 9.4.26.v20200117

I am using below code to load certificate.

```
 private final static String KEYSTORE_LOCATION = "/home/myproject/keystore.jks";

 SslContextFactory sslContextFactory = new SslContextFactory();
 sslContextFactory.setKeyStorePath(getKeystoreLocation());
 sslContextFactory.setKeyStorePassword("temp");
 sslContextFactory.setKeyManagerPassword("temp");

 private static String getKeystoreLocation() throws MalformedURLException {
    File file = new File(KEYSTORE_LOCATION);
    URL url = file.toURI().toURL();
    return url.toExternalForm();
}
```

I am getting `NullPointerException` for file. Can you please let me know what missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Use Jetty 9.4.46 (or newer).

Jetty 9.4.26 is subject to a few security issues now - see https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/security_reports.php for details

Is this `SslContextFactory` for Server or for Client use?

Server uses `SslContextFactory.Server`, and client uses `SslContextFactory.Client` implementations.  (your old version of Jetty might not have this distinction, which was a source of a few issues in the past)

The configured keystore/truststore file(s) needs to exist once you start Jetty.

Even if that keystore/truststore file is a dummy/empty one, it needs to exist.

Once you start, you can replace the keystore/truststore file(s) and the SslContextFactory will detect the changed file and reload the SslContextFactory.

Comment: Thank you Joakim for response. I am passing `keystore.jks` file path (on this path I have dummy `.jks` file) in `SslContextFactory` but I am always getting `NullPointerException`. So my question is on which path Jetty look for `.jks` file? Is there any specific path or any file system path will work

Comment: Use a recent version of Jetty 9.4.x (or newer), the error messages are clearer on newer versions.  Also make sure you are using the correct SslContextFactory implementation for your use case.

Comment: Hi Joakim, I have updated the question with my code I a using to load certificate. Could you please check whats wrong there and why I am getting `NullPointerException`. `.jks` file is present at start

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt can you give an example how to reload. I am also facing the same problem. It works if dummy non-empty keystore file is used at starting. Later, I am using https://gist.github.com/danielflower/f54c2fe42d32356301c68860a4ab21ed to call reload. But is there a way without using the FileWatcher, this can be achieved?

Comment: @ppb did you solve this problem? If yes, how?

Comment: @devd dont write your own FileWatcher, Jetty has it's own reload logic (built into SslContextFactory.Server) that detects changes, and is even aware of situations like a keystore that is in the middle of being updated (which your FileWatcher impl isn't doing).

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt I have posted the code which I'm using. Don't know why it's not working when using reload without putting it in FileWatcher

Comment: @devd if it's a supported version of Jetty (version 10+), then file an issue with details at https://github.com/jetty/jetty.project/issues/new/choose